# How to boot without 'nomodeset'?

Tags: nomodeset

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop, and am now trying to get it to run. In the grub menu, if I load it normally, all I get is a black screen. In order for it to boot successfully, I have to edit the menu item and add 'nomodeset'. With this, Ubuntu boots up.

Is there a fix for this, so that I don't have to constantly add the nomodeset? I tried to install the proprietary drivers but I still had the same problem.

My laptop specs are:

Intel Core i5-2410M (2.30GHz, Dual-Core)
6GB RAM
750GB HDD 7200rpm
AMD Radeon HD 6630 1GB

Answer (score 6):

You can edit the default grub boot options by typing in the terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Look for the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

and add nomodeset to the end:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

That way you won't have to keep adding it.  Then after saving changes and quitting the editor, type in the terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

to update your grub configuration.

Comment: Ah thanks Chan-Ho Suh, forgot the update-grub!

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and used this work-around as well. However, in this case my second screen is not detected anymore. I describe the problem [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/631339/ubuntu-14-04-alternative-to-nomodeset-second-screen-is-not-detected-which-gra). Is there any fix for that?

Answer (score 0):

I have spent more than 5 weeks on this. Finally the first solution that I found worked for me. While tried for the first time spelling mistake failed me.

`nomodeset` work fine but, it's a temporary solution to avoid the famous black screen on boot issue as it disables the intel graphics and usses gallium llvmpipe. Which causes several issues like VLC lags too much, can't change brightness.

If you have a Radeon card, replace `nomodeset` with `radeon.modeset=0`

My mistake : used `raedon.modeset=0` for the first time.

:D