# Why does Ubuntu, sometimes, fails to load?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

I recently installed **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** on my **SONY VAIO VPCEH** (with Windows 7 Home Basic
previously installed). Sometimes when I boot in Ubuntu, following things happen:

- Ubuntu loading screen seems to freeze.
- Esc key doesn't show installation progress.
- Hard-drive led doesn't glow.
- caps lock and scroll lock keys keep blinking.

I've to manually restart my laptop. On restart, Ubuntu loads normally.
What can I do to recover from present situation?

Comment: Likely a hardware issue. Try using "NOMODSET" when booting. Look at #1 answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/128128/how-to-boot-without-nomodeset

Comment: @blueXrider Most of the times, I am able to boot without problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a IRQ Conflict Problem. But could also be a kernel Panic Problem. You should try to add some boot parameters and check if they might help. You can add those to the grub menu.

More here:

[Boot Options (English)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions)

[Boot Parameters](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Booten) (German)

I sometimes had to use the following: (even in combination)

irqpoll
noapic, noagp, noapm
nolapic
pci=noacpi
pci=routeirq

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it's only just a lock screen problem and easy to bypass: just try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>.

What is happening is that system is running properly, as one can see by login from <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> **virtual terminal (VT)** or from a remote terminal, but the lock screen at VT7 , obtained by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> is freezed due to a light-locker screensaving program function who moves to the next VT8.

Forfurther details see [Screen Locking in Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/news/screen-locking-in-xubuntu-14-04/)