# Ubuntu 14.04. Alternative to nomodeset? Second screen is not detected. Which graphic drivers to use?

Tags: 14.04, boot, drivers, multiple-monitors, nomodeset

I read many threads that deal with this or similar issues, however, I did not manage to solve my problem yet. Here is the problem:

I received a Dell Precision M4800 that came with Windows 7. I wanted to install Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS alongside with Windows (which I have done many times before on other machines). I tried from DVD and also from USB but always ended up with a black screen after I selected the language that should be used.

There exist several threads about this problem and the work-around described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) worked for me: I booted Ubuntu using the options "nomodeset", "acpi = off" and "nolapic", and could then install Ubuntu as usual. 
When I then rebooted the system, I ended up with a purple screen. So I booted again, pressed "e" when the grub menu appeared, and replaced "quiet splash" by "nomodeset" as described in the above link. Ubuntu boots fine.
Then I added the "nomodeset" option to the grup file as described [in this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/38782#38782). Rebooting works fine now so I was happy since that seems not to have any weird side-effects according to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do).

However, now I wanted to connect a second screen to my laptop, which is recognized under Windows but is not under the fresh installed Ubuntu version, unfortunately. The reason for that is the "nomodeset" option which I need to boot my system successfully.

I probably need other drivers than I currently use. My current setting looks as follows:[image].

I selected the "proprietary, tested" version once and it then says that I use the recommended driver. However, when I then booted again, I could still enter my password but after logging in, I could not do anything (ctrl+alt+T did not open a terminal, there was no bar on the left anymore). I could get back to the current status by following the instructions made by [Marco Scannadinari](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver). Now I am not sure how to get the appropriate drivers for my graphics card. I run:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M] (rev a1)
```

and also:

```
grep -i chipset /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[     3.606] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
[     3.607] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
```

but I am not sure how to use this information.

My questions - which are highly interconnected - are therefore:

1) How do I get the second screen to work?

2) How to I get rid of the nomodeset option in /etc/default/grub without ending up with a purple/black screen?

3) Which drivers do I have to install for my graphics card and how to do this?

Thanks!

Edit:
I do not think that is a duplicate since it is not clear yet what the cause of my problem actually is. I already tried different drivers which did not solve my problem.If someone told me "The problem is that you use/installed the wrong drivers which can be seen from the screenshot you posted so you need to follow the instructions in the link Fabby provides to install the appropriate drivers" it would already be helpful. But even then it is hardly a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

Comment: which driver are you using intel or nouveau ? look in /var/log/Xorg.0.log. What is the ouput of xrandr when the second screen is connected ? what is there in Xorg.0.log about the second screen. ?

Comment: Surprisingly, it seems to work now. I might add a description of what I have done to solve it during the next days. But thanks a lot for the suggestions @solsTiCe!

Comment: @Cleb if you had fixed your issue, can you please post an answer with you solution?

Comment: @Dan: I'll try to do it,  yes (I noted down my steps somewhere which I have to dig out). If I remember correctly, I just tried once more to install the drivers and it worked out (after disabling my touch pad).

Comment: @cleb Great thanks! I'm having your exact problem, I've been trying for a while, but I can't seem to have my HDMI  working.

Comment: @Dan: Seems I only saved the command line history; so I have all the commands I used to solve the problem but don't remember what these commands were for. I could send you this file if you like!?

Comment: @Cleb no problems, I found a workaround for my problem. Not a perfect one, but it works.