# Cannot Install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (HC Died)

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, xhci-hcd

I need to install Ubuntu for a course that I am taking online and am having problems installing it. [This is the log that I freeze on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pbgw.jpg)

I have a gtx 960 (nvidia) and an amd 6300 cpu (64-bit).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need the `nomodeset` boot parameter when booting, installing and in the first boot after installed. Then you should install Nvidia drivers for you graphics card. Search for Additional Drivers, select and apply the highest version listed. Reboot.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu

Comment: It's the same as above except the first time you 'll be doing it in the live session. This is also relevant for booting the live session: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: I first tried my booting Ubuntu in legacy mode with nomodeset. I got another error that says initramfs. I read the link you gave me and I booted Ubuntu in UEFI mode. I am now at the GNU GRUB Ubuntu install window with no way to select nomodeset. @CelticWarrior

Comment: The first link, second comment, shows how. And this is a Q&A website, not a forum. Comments are for clarification, not for extended discussion or troubleshooting. Considering you may require those I suggest you post at Ubuntu forums.

Comment: @marsmission111 read the answer here (http://askubuntu.com/a/128137/10616) for how to enable `nomodeset` for every boot.  As well, ***do not be rude to users***.  This is your last warning about being rude.

Comment: @ThomasWard He/she also needs `nomodeset` in the live session, in order to install. Also needed *before* installing Nvidia proprietary drivers but not after. It's a temporary workaround, never intended to be permanent. Before, when booting in BIOS/Legacy mode, one would press F6 and select it; in UEFI mode it should show a Grub menu similar to the one in an already installed system and the parameters are edit by selecting the entry (Try Ubuntu) and pressing "e" to edit. Everything was/is explained in links in comments above.

Comment: @marsmission111 Because obsolete / too chatty / still containing some rudeness.  Moderation reasons.  That said, let's all go disappear and cool off for a while.  Leave this sit, alone, and let's all cool off a bit before returning to this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51829/discussion-on-question-by-marsmission111-cannot-install-ubuntu-16-04-lts-hc-die).

Comment: @CelticWarrior I have tried Thomas's link and the command is not recognized. I believe that this is because the link that Thomas sent me was for after I installed Ubuntu, the problem is, I have not installed Ubuntu. So I tried the 'e' method and put in 'nomodeset' and tried to install. After about five seconds I get a corrupted looking image on the screen and text saying 'HC has died'. Any recommendations?

Comment: Boot only with the hardware really needed, i.e., remove all USB devices except keyboard/mouse.

Comment: Tried it with only keyboard, mouse, and live USB. I encountered the same problem as before (listed above). @CelticWarrior

Comment: The *HC died* error is typical of a USB3.0 failure and one that rarely happens when installing. You may try disabling `xhci` (USB3.0) in UEFI settings -or- you may need another USB Flash drive -or- you may have a certain AMD chipset that requires either enabling or disabling IOMMU at UEFI settings plus additional boot parameters (`iommu=soft`) for booting the live session. Please use a different online help resource for the **even more extensive than previously thought troubleshooting** you need. Ubuntu Forums. Remeber to post there as many hardware info from the start.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Thanks for your help I will ask this question on another site. Have a good day :)